# Can I use a Global.asax's static property as a log4net logger?

Tags: c#, asp.net, log4net

I want do something like this:

```
<script RunAt="server">

private static log4net.ILog _logger = null;
public static log4net.ILog Logger
{ get { return _logger; } }

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure();
    _logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger("DtWebLogger");
}

....
</script>
```

I'm wondering after this I can use the same logger object in every pages.

So, is this possible? or Where can I instant a global instance of a Logger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your inited is right and log4net.LogManager.GetLogger already use one instance no need do it again.

Answer (score 2):

You don't want a global instance of Logger. Rather, you want one per class. Each class where you want to log should have something like this:

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog _logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyClass));
```

The type information is used as part of the logger output. You can also make your own class that wraps ILog and gives you a constructor that pulls the type of the current class from the StackFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare it as a property and use like this:

```
private static readonly log4net.ILog Log = log4net.LogManager     
.GetLogger(.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

As stated, you don't want a global logger. Declare on nested scopes.